# Cookie is not defined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I'm getting 'Cookie is not defined' error from this code. What went wrong with this code? Please help to fix it.

```
$('#save-dashboard').on('click', function (e) {
        var filtersNew = $("#graph-filters").val();
        if (!filtersNew) {
            alert('No Filters!');
        }
        if (cookie.enabled())
        {
            cookie.defaults.path = '/';
            var cookieFilters = cookie.get('cookie-filter-list');
            if (cookieFilters) {
                cookieFilters = cookieFilters + '#' + filtersNew;
                cookie.defaults.expires = 30;
                cookie.set('cookie-filter-list', cookieFilters);
                cookie.defaults.path = '/';
            }
        } else {
            cookie.defaults.expires = 30;
            cookie.set('filter-list', cookieFilters);
            cookie.defaults.path = '/';
        }
    });
```

I have set `app.use(express.cookieParser())`

Comment: the compiler is right, what the hell **is** `cookie` ? what does `cookie.enabled()` mean ?

Comment: Where does your cookie variable came from? Do you have a declaration for it? If not, then that's why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should proceed with cookie:

1. Open your terminal,
2. Browse to your app folder

$ npm install cookie-parser

You must import cookieparser in your app.

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');    
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
```

`cookie-parser` parses Cookie header and populate `req.cookies` with an object keyed by the cookie names.

To set a new cookie define a new route in your express app like

```
app.get('/cookie',function(req, res){
     res.cookie(cookie_name , 'cookie_value').send('Cookie is set');
});
```

To get a cookie;

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Cookies :  ", req.cookies);
});
```

You can set expiration time in cookie

```
res.cookie(name , 'value', {expire : new Date() + 9999});
```

and finally to clear cookie

```
app.get('/clearcookie', function(req,res){
     res.clearCookie('cookie_name');
     res.send('Cookie deleted');
});
```